# Android how to pass array of modal class and parameters using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

//Here is a data for the modal class

```
busi_data[otp_verified]: 
busi_data[pan]: 
busi_data[gstin]: 
busi_data[doc]: pan
busi_data[business_name]: 
busi_data[entity_type]: 
busi_data[mobile]: 
busi_data[customer_email]: 
busi_data[mode]: 
busi_data[ses_email]: 
busi_data[pluskey]: 
busi_data[otp_auth]: 
busi_data[otp]: 
operation:
```

I am using retrofit for sending data to server.i want to pass a modal class as a parameter.please help to solve.

Comment: What do you need exactly? What is your endpoint you want to achieve and what information you want to send?

Comment: just pass the list of model class as a parameter (@Field ArrayList<Your Model Class file Name>) in your interface

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can user below code for pass model class in api

```
@POST(Constants.ApiMethods.GET_LOGIN)
Flowable<GenericModel<LoginResponse>> doLogin(@Body RequestBody requestBody);


    Flowable<GenericModel<LoginResponse>> getusers = mRestApis.doLogin(Utility.getRequest(HobbsRepairApp.getGsonWithExpose().toJson(LoginRequest)));
    getusers.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                String message = ((HttpException) throwable).response().errorBody().string();
                GenericModel<LoginResponse> userBaseResponse = HobbsRepairApp.getGsonWithExpose().fromJson(message, GenericModel.class);
                return userBaseResponse;                })
            .subscribe(responsData -> {
                if (responsData != null) {
                    GenericModel<LoginResponse> responseGenericModel = responsData;
                    if ((responseGenericModel.getStatus() == 200) && (responseGenericModel.getResponse() != null)) {
                        LoginResponse loginResponse = responseGenericModel.getResponseModel(LoginResponse.class);
                        loginResponse.setMessage(responseGenericModel.getMessage());
                        mEventBus.post(loginResponse);
                    } else {
                        mEventBus.post(new APIError(105, responseGenericModel.getMessage()));
                    }
                }
            });


public static RequestBody getRequest(String reqString) {
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
    return RequestBody.create(mediaType, reqString);
}

 public static Gson getGsonWithExpose() {
    if (mGson != null) {
        mGson = null;
    }
    mGson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    return mGson;
}
```